# Make diagonal line for DIV square

Tags: html, css

I want to show the diagonal line inside div,but it shows just the 135 degree line.
Of course there is `135deg` , but how can I change the div degree depending on div size???

```css
#ConnectLine{
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:5;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, transparent 49%, black 49%, black 51%, transparent 51%, transparent);
 
}
```

```html
<div id="ConnectLine" style="width:100px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/juicypixels/pen/gPravL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of `calc` in `css`

```css
#ConnectLine {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 1px),  black calc(50% - 1px), black 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="ConnectLine" style="width: 100px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you its quite helpful calc function...